# c++, OpenFileDialog.Filter, file name

Tags: c++, winapi

I need to use the [`OpenFileName()` dialog box](https://zetcode.com/gui/winapi/dialogs/), and want to filter `CSV files` starting with some specific alphabet, eg, "`m`"-> `"myspecific.csv"`

How can I do it?

```
OPENFILENAME ofn;
ofn.lpstrFile[0] = '\0';
ofn.lpstrFilter = L"CSV Files (*.csv)\0*.csv\0All Files (*.*)\0*.*\0";// How to add "m" in filter and what is role of \0 here?
```

Comment: Have you tried to [read the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commdlg/ns-commdlg-openfilenamea)?

Comment: And note that `ofn.lpstrFile[0] = '\0';` will not work very well.

Comment: *CGi03* 's answer [I tested](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/7cbd99ac1d2b4a0beffbaba29ea63d024ceff700/Samples/Win7Samples/winui/shell/appplatform/fileisinuse/fileisinusesample.cpp#L468) works as expect. @Shahgee , Any update?

Comment: @wohlstad  The link I have pasted"https://zetcode.com/gui/winapi/dialogs/" has only '\0';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must put the letter before the star.

```
ofn.lpstrFilter = L"CSV Files (*.csv)\0m*.csv\0All Files (*.*)\0*.*\0";
```

Comment: @wohlstad, A string literal has an implied null character at the end of the string.

Comment: From the documentation: `To retrieve ..., use the string "All Files\0*.*\0\0"` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commdlg/ns-commdlg-openfilenamea).

Comment: I tested it and it seems like 1 `\0` is enough. I wonder if that is a mistake in the documentation.

Comment: yes, but if you put two, it makes three with the one at the end of the literal string.

Comment: I agree. So the example in the documentation has a superflous '\0'.

Comment: @wohlstad Yes, the documentation has a superfluous `\0` character. Very likely the result of giving the argument type the wrong name (*"double-null terminated string"*). For a more accurate mental model read this: [What is the format of a double-null-terminated string with no strings?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20091008-00/?p=16443)